# Inserting a spark RDD, which contains n number of scala class objects into cassandra db

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector, objectmapper

Say i have five objects of a  scala class and i need to frame a spark RDD with the five objects and push that RDD into cassandra table 
my cassandra table "person" has three fields (pId,pName,pAge)
and

```
val object 1= new myclass(1,"abc",24)
val object2 = new myclass(2,"pqr",23)
val object3 = new myclass(3,"xyz",26)
```

How do i form an rdd of these three objects ?
is the below line possible

```
val collection=context.parallelize(Seq(object1,object2,object3))
```

and if an RDD can be made .. how can i push that RDD to cassandra table to insert three rows in that table "person"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to just make a CaseClass where the classes match the Rows in your table

```
case class PersonRow(pID: int, pName: String, pAge: Int)
context.parallelize(Seq(
  PersonRow(1, "abc", 24),
  PersonRow(2, "pqr", 23),
  PersonRow(3, "xyz", 26)
)).saveToCassandra("ks","person")
```

For more information see the [Spark Cassandra Connector Documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-a-collection-of-scala-objects)

### Edit

`mapToRow` is unnecessary in Scala code as it basically a workaround for the lack of implicits in Scala. SaveToCassandra usually uses an implicit `RowWriterFactory`, Scala can make this for you by looking at the RDD class type. In Java the factory must be made manually.

```
scala> class SomeRandomClass (val k:Int, val v:Int) {
     | def fun() = {println("lots of fun")}
     | val somethingElse:Int = 5
     | }
defined class SomeRandomClass

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 10).map( x => new SomeRandomClass(x,x)).saveToCassandra("test","test")

scala> sc.cassandraTable("test","test")
res4: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[7] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15

scala> sc.cassandraTable("test","test").collect
res5: Array[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = Array(CassandraRow{k: 5, v: 5}, CassandraRow{k: 10, v: 10}, CassandraRow{k: 1, v: 1}, CassandraRow{k: 8, v: 8}, CassandraRow{k: 2, v: 2}, CassandraRow{k: 4, v: 4}, CassandraRow{k: 7, v: 7}, CassandraRow{k: 6, v: 6}, CassandraRow{k: 9, v: 9}, CassandraRow{k: 3, v: 3})
```

*Note this only works because a mapping can be found between the fields of the class (k and v) to columns "k and v" in the table.*

Comment: can it be done without using case classes and passing an Rdd to savetocssandra , wherein RDD contains a collection of objects
like
 val empObj :emp = new emp(1,2,"yyyy")
val collection = context.parallelize(Seq(empObj))
collection.saveToCassandra("smart", "emp")

Comment: You can use tuples, or java Mbean like classes (see docs), or CassandraRow objects.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/7b0147bed6e5d7d5712a7489f3e1c00cf3a43d7c/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/CassandraRow.scala

A generic class can't be mapped since there is no way to know what the mapping should be between the classes and the CassandraTables.

Comment: Is there any scala api equivalent to "mapToRow" api available in spark with java api, so that we can directly map the class structure to the RDD.

Comment: mapToRow is just a wrapper around creating the rowwriterfactory which is done implicitly in the scala code. Basically this means when you do rdd.saveToCassandra(ks,table) there are implicit args (implicitly RowWriterFactory[yourClass]). This means there is never a reason to actually call mapToRow in Scala. If a rowWriterFactory could be made for your class, the compiler would do so. 

I'll add an example

Comment: So you mean to say , by implementing my own rowWriterFactory method  for my class ,i can customise the column mapping in saveToCassandra function in scala .. right ?

Comment: You could do it much easier use by using a  columnselector